# How to print out errors (including syntax) from Py_CompileString?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* code = Py_CompileString(text, "(text)", Py_single_input);
if (!code) {
    PyErr_Print();
    return;
}
```

Does not produce any text.  I understand that there is a `sys.stderror` but is there no simpler way of dealing with this other than creating a callback and custom function?

Answer (score 2):

Discovered this finally:

```
    PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
    PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
    PyObject* utf = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(pvalue);
    Assert(utf);
    char* buffer = PyBytes_AsString(utf);
```

Comment: For completeness, followed by `Py_DECREF(utf); Py_DECREF(ptype); Py_XDECREF(pvalue); Py_XDECREF(ptraceback);`  Note: `pvalue` and `ptraceback` may be `NULL`, so `Py_XDECREF` is used, and conversion of `pvalue` into `char*` should be protected with `if (pvalue != NULL) { ... }`.

Comment: for Python3 I changed this to use `PyObject* str = PyObject_Str(pvalue), Py_ssize_t size;char const *buffer = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(str, &size)`;